# How to iterate through a symfony (Doctrine) result object

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following query:

```
function indexAction()
{
    $u = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Users")->findAll( \Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY );

    return $this->render("default/test.html.twig", ["users" => $u]);
}
```

And I loop through it in Twig Template with this loop:

```
{%  for item in users %}
<li>{{ item.email }} : </li>
{%  endfor %}
```

And I encounter this error:

```
Impossible to access a key "name" on an object of class "AppBundle\Entity\Users" that does not implement ArrayAccess interface in default/test.html.twig at line
```

Comment: Did you also tried {{ item.property }}? Since how it looks to my you're trying to echo out an object

Comment: Yes. I updated the question's code. Indeed I just did a mistake in pasting codes here..

Comment: Try to omit '\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY' argument of `findAll` method and make sure that you have a public getEmail() getter in `Users` entity.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong. You pass `users` variable to the template, but you are using `myItems` in the `for` loop.

Try this:

```
{% for item in users %}
    {{ dump(item) }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I updated the question. I pasted a wrong code. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Still think there is a mismatch between your posted code and your error message.  The error message indicates you are trying to access a property called 'name' (not 'email') as your twig code shows.  Make sure you have accessors (getName(), getEmail() etc) defined.  As mentioned in the comments, findAll takes no arguments so the this HYDRATE_ARRAY stuff is not doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Does your class implements ArrayAccess in your entity definition ?

```
class Foo implements ArrayAccess
```

You will have to add several methods in your class for this to work :

*To implement ArrayAccess you need to implement four methods: offsetExists, offsetGet, offsetSet and offsetUnset. ArrayAccess::offsetExists must return a boolean, offsetGet can return any valid PHP type while offsetSet and offsetUnset should not return any value. Once you implement these methods you can treat an object as if it is an array for the purposes of saving and retrieving properties*

More details [here](http://jeremycook.ca/2012/01/22/implementing-the-arrayaccess-interface/).